# MVC 4 - How to save/update data into multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can somebody help me on how to update data (from view) into multiple database tables using a ViewModel?

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class myViewModel
{
    public int tbl_master_id{ get; set; }   
    public int tbl_details_id {get; set;}     
    public string case_number{ get; set; }
    public string claim_num{ get; set; }
}
```

[NOTE: case_number belongs to tbl_master, while claim_num belongs to tbl_details table]

I was able to retrieve and display the data (from multiple tables) into the view. However, now I'm stuck on how can I update the above tables with the new data. Most of the examples are 1-1 relationship the mapping is automatic, but in this case the data belongs to multiple tables.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any updating of database from your view.  Database logic does not belong there.

Comment: I didn't mean updating in the view, I meant updating the database tables in the controller when I post the form using BeginForm.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should have an action method marked with `[HttpPost]` that accepts `myViewModel`, in your controller, you execute code to save the data as needed.  If you have multiple tables, this will require multiple updates or inserts.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(myViewModel model) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // do your database updates.
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: In this section of code:

 if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // do your database updates.
    }

How can I update the table using the Id that I pass into the action? I am having a hard-time in creating a LING query to do this something like that in code. Let's say my table in tbl_master, I have to update the field case_number into xxxvalue of the record whose master_id = id? 

Thank you.

Comment: @user1953372 - You just retrieve the record(s) you want, update the data you want to update, then call `SaveChanges()`.  You don't have to (and probably cannot) do it in one command.